# How to use synctex?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, viewers, forward-inverse-search

We are preparing an editor and pdf viewer in live code.
Could you tell me how to use synctex in this application

How to create forward search and reverse search?
What are the things i need?

Comment: For reverse search you need previewer, which allows this, For example for pdf documents I use Sumatra. Depends of used editor, you need to set this option in it. For example in WinEdt, you need to select "use-synctex switch ...", set "SynTeX swith: `--syntctex=-1`, and "syncteTeX Filetype:" `.syntex`. All this option are in Option/Execution modes/PDF Viewer.

Comment: Do you mean you are _creating_ and editor/previwered or that you are _using_ one?

Comment: if we create a text editor, is it works?. What are the things to be switch inside the editor to work. i am using acrobat.

Comment: No joseph, i created only a plain editor.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about how SyncTeX works internally (in order to add SyncTeX support to an editor you've created) or are you asking about how to turn on SyncTeX support for an editor you're using?

Comment: @SamjithDasan As I remember acrobat locks the pdf file. You may try sumatrapdf on windows or skim.app on mac. I'm guessing you are writing an editor, for that you need to be able to get and send the sync message between the editor and the pdf viewer, for example through a command line interface.

Comment: yes, I need my editor for synctex support. i am using linux os. Is there any option to send message by commandline?

Comment: Well, it depends on the viewer, of course. You need a viewer which will understand the message. Then you'd have to write the code so that the editor sends the message. That's for forwards. For reverse, you have to create the editor so that it responds to a message from the viewer. You need a viewer which can send the messages but usually you can configure the particular command to send to the editor. So you just create an interface which is convenient for you, I guess.  Have you considered using an existing editor rather than writing a new one?

Comment: What i did is, I created a text field in livecode (left side) and give some functionality in that field to made it as editior and i have a image area (right side), where i wish to show pdf (acrobat). what type of message should be the editor send, to understand the viewer about the line number and page number.

Comment: Please help! if i used browser instead of acrobat, is it possible?

Comment: Hi samjith, I have similar problem right now. I need to get inverse and foward search in my custom editor and pdf viewer. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, All members in groups afraid to give the answer.